# How does a key-value pair outside of an object literal still produce a value?

Tags: javascript, expression

Try to type

```
donald: 'duck'
```

or even

```
{donald: 'duck'} // hint: this is considered a scope block instead of an object literal by the console
```

On the console (I've tested node, chrome, and IE).

I personally got **"duck"** as output... can someone explain me why?

Comment: an object (or a function, etc) is a "scope block" (the terms aren't mutually exclusive)

Comment: I think `donald` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: You're typing a key : value, it send you the values back. Works also with foo : bar. The why of this behaviour can be questionned but is truly unpertinent, as i could question the why of your question :)

Comment: The why is the end of a javascript dispute with my collegues about block scopes and object literals :)

Comment: @Pamlam A scope block and an object literal are not the same. For instance, `{ x: 3, y: 3 }` (scope block) is syntactically invalid but `({ x: 3, y: 3 })` (object literal) is not.

Comment: @JorelAmthor This is not the case, see the comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside of object literals, the `[identifier]:` syntax defines a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Basically, a label names a specific point of the program. They are a rare feature of JavaScript, but can be used when using `break` or `continue` in nested for loops:

```
outer_loop:
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  inner_loop:
  for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    // will break inner_loop as normal
    break;

    // will break outer_loop instead
    break outer_loop;
  }
}
```

However, if you simply declare a label for some statement, but never use it, it effectively works as if it was never there. Thus the statement

```
donald: 'duck'
```

will be the same as just

```
'duck'
```

since the label functionality is never used.

Comment: Never heard about the label feature, it was quite confusing XD, I will add the link provided by Andy in the comments to complete your answer!